# Calling Thread cannot access this object (Dispatcher.CheckAccess)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, serial-port

I'm trying to use serial communication in WPF with vb.net and the only successful thing that I can do is sending data. When it comes to receiving data I have received different errors, and this one is the hardest for me to get over with. I tried to apply the windows form code when we want to receive data by using the Control.InvokeRequired, but since this is WPF this was transferred to Dispatcher.CheckAccess(). Everytime I load the program the transmission is ok but reception gives me error of System.InvalidOperation:'The calling thread cannot acces this object because a different thread owns it.' I looked at other solutions but none have worked.

Are there other solutions/process for receiving data from the other side?

I tried various examples from both windows document and other sites, but none was successful in WPF application.

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows

Class MainWindow
    Private WithEvents serport As New SerialPort

    Private Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String)

    Private Sub onLoad()
        Dim ports As String() = SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        Dim port As String

        For Each port In ports
            comPortCombo.Items.Add(port)
        Next port


    End Sub


    Private Sub ConButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles conButton.Click
        'serport = New SerialPort()

        If (comPortCombo.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select COM port!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        serport.PortName = comPortCombo.Text
        serport.BaudRate = baudCombo.Text

        serport.Open()


        transButton.IsEnabled = True
        conButton.IsEnabled = False
        disconButton.IsEnabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisconButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles disconButton.Click
        serport.Close()
        disconButton.IsEnabled = False
        transButton.IsEnabled = False
        conButton.IsEnabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub TransButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles transButton.Click
        serport.Write(transTextBox.Text & vbCrLf)
        transTextBox.Clear()

    End Sub


    Private Sub serport_datareceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles serport.DataReceived
        'recTextBox.Text = receiveserialdata()

        'with serForm's function???
        ReceivedText(serport.ReadLine())
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
        If recTextBox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Dispatcher.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})

        Else
            recTextBox.Text &= [text]
        End If

    End Sub

    'Function receiveserialdata() As String
    '    ' receive strings from a serial port.
    '    Dim returnstr As String = ""
    '    Try
    '        Do
    '            Dim incoming As String = serport.ReadExisting()
    '            If incoming Is Nothing Then
    '                Exit Do
    '            Else
    '                returnstr &= incoming & vbCrLf
    '            End If
    '        Loop
    '    Catch ex As TimeoutException
    '        returnstr = "error: serial port read timed out."
    '    Finally
    '        If serport IsNot Nothing Then serport.Close()
    '    End Try

    '    Return returnstr
    'End Function

End Class
```

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'`

Comment: The `DataReceived` event is raised on a secondary thread. Therefore you can't access UI elements directly from the event handler. Replace your `ReceivedText` method content with `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Function() recTextBox.AppendText(text))`.

Comment: `Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal text As String)
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Function() recTextBox.AppendText(text))
End Sub`

Comment: It says that the expression does not produce a value.

Comment: Try this: `Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal responseText As String) Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() recTextBox.AppendText(responseText)  End Sub) End Sub`

Comment: Thank you. This one helped solve the problem, but I didn't include the end sub after the appendtext response text as it creates another error. This works now, thank you once again.

Comment: @BionicCode You should post this as an answer so it can be accepted.